# Como executar uma função powershell chamando o arquivo .ps1?

Tags: windows, servidor, script, powershell, hyper-v

tudo bem com vocês?

Solicito um auxilio criei uma função que faz backup de maquinas virtuais essa função recebe dois parâmetros o nome do servidor e o nome da VM. Preciso chamar função executando o arquivo .ps1, já tentei executar o arquivo e passar os parâmetros para função de diversas formas, mas o comando "powershell" é executado e nenhuma ação é realizada ou seja a função que esta no arquivo não é executada, mas quando executo a função no Powershell ISE ou faço o dot-source tudo funciona as mil maravilhas, veja abaixo os métodos que tenho utilizado para chamar a função:

**usando o operado call "&"**

> powershell.exe –command "& { C:\script_backup\Exportar-Vm.ps1 'SERVIDO' 'NOMEDAVM' }"

**usando o operado call "&" e fazendo o dot-source**

> powershell.exe –command "& { .  C:\script_backup\Exportar-Vm.ps1 'SERVIDO' 'NOMEDAVM' }"
>
> powershell.exe –NonInteractive –ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted –command "& {C:\script_backup\Exportar-Vm.ps1 SERVIDOR NOMEDAVM}"
>
> powershell -command {Exportar-VM -serverName SRV-LIDER-TEST -vmName VM01}
>
> powershell ""& C:\script_backup\Exportar-vm SERVIDOR NOMEDAVM""
>
> powershell -Command "& C:\script_backup\Exportar-vm -serverName SERVIDOR -vmName NOMEDAVM"
>
> powershell.exe -command  . .\Exportar-VM.ps1
>
> powershell.exe –file " 'C:\script_backup\Exportar-Vm.ps1' 'SERVIDO' 'NOMEDAVM'"

[image: resultado do comando]

e outras formas não listadas, todos os comando acima são executado (devolve o prompt mas não executam a função que esta no arquivo "Exportar-Vm.ps1", o pior é que não lança um erro na tela e nem gera um log de informação de erro de nada, já não sei mais o que fazer.

Obs: Estou utilizando o servidor "Microsoft Hyper-v Server R2"

Já habilitei a execução de scripts no meu servidor veja
[image: Comando Get-ExecutionPolicy -List]

Segue abaixo o script que esta no arquivo .ps1 que estou tentando executar

```
function Exportar-Vm
{
    [CmdletBinding()]

    param(
         [string]$serverName,
         [string]$vmName
    )

    process{
        # Vars
        $backupPath = "D:\BACKUPs"
        $fileset = "include"
        $typeParameter = "VirtualMachine"
        $pathScriptBackup = "C:\scripts_backup"
        $FileMessage = "exportarvm.dll"
        $logName = "Evento de backup - Bacula-FD"
        $logSource = "Bacula-BackupVm"

        $getVm = Get-Vm -ComputerName $serverName -Name $vmName
        if(($getVm.GetType().Name  -eq $typeParameter) -and ($getVm.Name -eq $vmName)){
                # verify if exist file in directory BACKUPs and remove. The objective this command line is remove file "include". Just file in the directory
                Get-ChildItem -Path $backupPath"*" -File | Remove-Item
                $Date = Get-Date -UFormat "%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M-%S"
                #create directory
                $dir = New-Item -Name "$vmName-$date" -ItemType "directory" -Path $backupPath -Force
                # out file path in file include
                $dir.FullName | Out-File "$backupPath\$fileset"
                # Export vm
                Export-VM -Name $vmName -Path $dir -AsJob
                Write-EventLog -LogName $logName -Source $logSource -EntryType Information -EventId 1 -Message " $vmName exportada com sucesso! Para $dir"
        }else{
            Write-EventLog -LogName $logName -Source $logSource -EntryType Error -EventId 3 -Message " Erro maquina virtual não exportada - Backup não realizado"
        }
        Write-EventLog -LogName $logName -Source $logSource -EntryType Information -EventId 2 -Message "Fim da execução script de backup."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**O problema central nestas tentativas é que o script `Exporta-VM.ps1` apenas carrega a função `Exportar-VM`, mas não a invoca.**

Sugiro 3 soluções distintas.

**Solução 1**

Manter o script original inalterado e realizar a chamada de fora do PowerShell da seguinte maneira

```
powershell.exe -command "& { . ./Exporta-Vm.ps1; Exportar-VM 'MeuServidor' 'MinhaVM' }"
```

**Solução 2**

Criar um script intermediário com o seguinte código:

```
. ./Exporta-VM.ps1
Exportar-VM $Args[0] $Args[1]
```

E realizar sua chamada de fora do PowerShell da seguinte maneira:

```
powershell.exe -file Intermediario.ps1 "Meu Servidor" "Minha VM"
```

**Solução 3**

Alterar o script original para receber dois parâmetros, depois carregar a função normalmente, depois invocar a função repassando os dois parâmetros como argumentos da função. O script teria o formato:

```
param(
  [string]$a,
  [string]$b
)

function Exportar-Vm
{
    [CmdletBinding()]

    param(
         [string]$serverName,
         [string]$vmName
    )

    process{
        ####################################
        # Insira sua função original aqui! #
        ####################################
    }
}

Exportar-Vm $a $b
```

O script seria chamado de fora do PowerShell da seguinte maneira:

```
powershell -file Exporta-VM.ps1 "Meu Servidor" "Minha VM"
```

Comment: A solução 2 resolveu o problema. Obrigado.